# Return some variables along with a list of models in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a class that is defined as below

```
public class Classroom
    {
        public string Teacher { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public List<Students> studentsList { get; set; }
    }
```

I had a stored procedure where it is able to return the list of students into the studentsList. Currently, i would like to pass back 2 more values (Teacher and Location) in the same stored procedure. I am curious whether the stored procedure is able to complete above requirements?

Comment: How are you calling your stored procedure from c#?

Comment: Using Dapper.SqlMapper library Query<T> and call .ToList() to map it to the studentsList.

Comment: You have many options, you can return multiple result sets and map them to the relevant classes, return a json object and then parse it extract values....

Comment: You need to set the parameter to output : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/163/returning-sql-server-stored-procedure-parameter-values-to-a-calling-stored-procedure/

Comment: @ChewHongYu Can you post more code and also an example of the stored procedure that you are calling?

Answer (score -1):

Use output parameters. You can return as many as you like. [Here](https://code-maze.com/csharp-pass-output-parameters-to-stored-procedures-dapper/) is a full example with Dapper and Sql Server.

You can use this to return things like ids of just inserted rows, or @@rowcount.You can also access info messages generated by your sql.